# Longest common subsequence—where is my infinite loop?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, subsequence

I'm trying to implement the longest common subsequence algorithm in Ruby, but I'm getting the `stack level too deep` error message. I know this probably means I have an infinite loop, but I cannot spot it. Below is my best attempt—where am I going wrong?

```
def lcs(string1, string2)
  if !(string1.chars.any? { |x| string2.include?(x)})
    return ""
  elsif string1[-1] == string2[-1]
    return lcs(string1[0..-2], string2[0..-2]) + string1[-1]
  else
    x = lcs(string1, string2[0..-1])
    y = lcs(string1[0..-1], string2)
    x.length > y.length ? x : y
  end
end
```

n.b. I'm trying to return the subsequence itself, not its length.

Comment: You should begin by explaining what is meant by the "longest common subsequence".

Comment: You might want to take a look at [triez](https://github.com/luikore/triez). It has an example for this exact problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with a sample string: `abcd` and `bc` and step through it.

You'll realise that these two lines have issues:

```
x = lcs(string1, string2[0..-1])
y = lcs(string1[0..-1], string2)
```

Because `'abcd'[0..-1] -> 'abcd'` so the moment it reaches `x = ...` line it'll get stuck.

It should be `[0..-2]` instead.

Also, you can use `if string1.chars.none? { |x| string2.include?(x)}`
to replace `if !(string1.chars.any? { |x| string2.include?(x)})`

Comment: Of course! Thank you Ho Man, not sure how I missed that.